# Property 'map' does not exist on type 'object'

Tags: angular, typescript

I recently got into Angular and TypeScript and was trying to learn something and found a particular project that I can try (I can edit in the link if anyone wants to see the project) *(Trying to read json data from pokemon api)*

Property 'map' does not exist on type 'object' is in this line.
`.then(items => items.map((item, idx) =>`

Here is the full code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class PokedexService {
  private baseUrl: string = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/';
  private baseSpriteUrl: string = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getPokemon(offset: number, limit: number) {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}?offset=${offset}&limit=${limit}`)
      .toPromise()

      //.then(response => response.json().results)
      //.map((results = > response.json()))

      .then(items => items.map((item, idx) => {
        const id: number = idx + offset + 1;
        return {
          name: item.name,
          sprite: `${this.baseSpriteUrl}${id}.png`,
          id
        };
      }));
  }
}
```

When I was trying to run the project I first got an error for the json part(json does not exist on object) of this script then I learned that with new updates you do not need those lines so I commented them out. (Don't know if it is right or wrong) And after that I got the error that I'm asking right now.

I hope I didn't do anything wrong, and waiting for any guidance.
Again, I'm new in this area but know coding.

Comment: The error told you everything you need to know. Your `items` is an object, not an array. You should also not use `toPromise`, rather just `subscribe` to the observable.

Comment: The error explains exactly what is wrong. Have you tried to console.log(items)? What do they look like?
You can only use `.map' with arrays.

Comment: Use `items.results.map(......)`

Comment: @ritaj I changed my code according to your comment, it took me a while but it worked. Right now I can run(ng serve) the app. Only thing I need to check whether if I got my data set or not. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will declare the returned value (i.e. Items[]) you will be able to run .map
I usually have separation between the API services and the component, so it looks like this:

api.service.ts

```
public GetPokemon(): Observable<Items[]> {
        const url = this.url_to_backend_method;
        return this.http.get<Items[]>(url)
            .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
    }
```

component.ts

```
private getPokemon() {
        this.api.GetPokemon().subscribe(
            items => items.map((item, idx) => {
                ** run your logic here **};
            }, error => {
                ** deal with error here **
            });
    }
```

Hope this helps